# identifying locator using CSS

Tags: css, selenium

Issue with identifying locator using CSS.

10 elements are existing  with same locator name in the webpage. Every web element xpath is same. xpath value is

```
 //div[@class='thumb_image']
```

The size of the web element list is 10. If i want to access the 5th element then i can use the index value `(//div[@class='thumb_image'])[5]`. How can i fetch the fifth element using cascading style sheet locator application. Could you please help me to fix the issue?

Comment: Hi Sai! Not sure this passes as a question. Please add some details + code examples. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867836/how-to-select-elements-with-the-same-css-selector/57867981#57867981

Answer (score 0):

Try as .thumb_image:nth-of-type(5)

Follow the link for more details:

[How to select elements with the same css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867836/how-to-select-elements-with-the-same-css-selector/57867981#57867981)